# Import behaviour when file/folder has the same name

Tags: ecmascript-6

ES6 newbie here. Maybe it's an easy question, but haven't found any useful info on this. I have `modals.js` file and `modals` folder in `actions` directory.

How can I tell javascript whether I want to import a file or a folder if they have same name?

My expectation is that:

```
import {...} from './actions/modals'
```

Can be treated either as `modals.js` file or `modals/index.js`. Is there any widely spread solution that will work on any bundler, that will guarantee what exactly do I require?

I understand that I can try to use '.js' extension like:

```
import {...} from './actions/modals.js'
```

But my research shown that not all builders support file extension.

I would really appreciate your help in my ES6 learning

Comment: Usually just to avoid general confusion I'd say having name overlaps like that should be avoided. Can you expand on "my research shown that not all builders support file extension" ? What research? What bundlers?

Comment: @loganfsmyth https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import `module-name` section

Comment: @loganfsmyth I think, that avoiding such confusions is definitely not the case. I mean, that I've already avoided it, but I think that we should find a real solution here :)

Comment: Does `from './actions/modals/';` work for folders? Using the extension is definitely the way for files.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Looks like folder works with slash in the end. But I am still a bit concerned about extension because of 'MDN' statement....

Comment: What statement? You need to be specific.

Comment: I cannot imagine a packer/bundler that does *not* support file extensions. Which one are you thinking of?

Comment: @loganfsmyth @Bergi In https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import regarding `module-name` -> "This is often a relative or absolute path name to the .js file containing the module, excluding the .js extension. Certain bundlers may permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment. Only single quotes and double quotes Strings are allowed." From my point of view "may permit' means that some of them don't permit extensions (I can't imagine what exactly, I just refer this doc statement).

Comment: But "any" bundler doesn't matter, just whichever bundler you decide to use. Most of them either require the extension or automatically detect it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Ok, that works! Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Using `.js` as file extension is not an option if I want to work with `typescript` files... having the same issue, and can't figure out a solution which works. Having no naming overlaps I think in this case is not a good advice, what is causing my naming overlapse currently is that I am trying to define a sub object related to the specific object which is named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining everything that was mentioned in the comments I've ended up in a way to always specify either `/` in the end if I refer to a folder or `.js` if I refer to specific file.